# C Function Returns Integer Instead of Float - Python ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a very simple C program `spammodule.c` that looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float calculate_change(float previous, float current) {
    if (previous == current) {
        return 0;
    }
    float change;
    change = (current - previous) / previous;
    return change * 100.0;
};
```

Then I compile the program using `gcc -fPIC -shared -o spammodule.so spammodule.c`.

Then I import the compiled C program using ctypes and call this function from a python module `main.py`:

```py
from ctypes import *

so_file = '/home/folder/spammodule.so'
main = CDLL(so_file)
print(main.calculate_change(c_float(100), c_float(200)))
```

This should return 100.00 which is the percentage change going from 100 to 200, but instead it prints `2` on console. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Suggest reading the [ctypes documentation on return types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types) and [argument types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Python `ctypes` documentation:

> By default functions are assumed to return the C `int` type. Other return types can be specified by setting the `restype` attribute of the function object.

You don't set the `restype` attribute, so it's assumed that your function returns an `int`. In the same way that you have to explicitly set the types of parameters (with `c_float(100)`), you also have to explicitly set the return type.

Before the call to `main.calculate_change`, you should do the following:

```
main.calculate_change.restype = c_float
```

Comment: OP should also set `main.calculate_change.argtypes = c_float, c_float` so they can call `main.calculate_change(100,200)` without explicitly wrapping in `c_float`.